# Using a powershell loop to copy files to pattern-aware directories

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, copy-item

I have a directory A in which containing the sub directories `a, b, c, d`, each sub-directory contains timestamped folders, example `20230120`, and files whose names end with the date and time of day example `file-202301200545`

What I want is to copy the files whose names end with today's date to the folder with today's date.

Sorry, it's a bit complicated to explain but I hope you understand it.

I wrote a script that performs this action but on the condition that I fix each directory.

```
$pattern = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd

$path = "D:\A\b\"
$Dest = "D:\A\b\\$pattern"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Filter *$pattern* | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Move-Item -Destination $Dest

$path = "D:\A\c\"
$Dest = "D:\A\c\\$pattern"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Filter *$pattern* | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Move-Item -Destination $Dest

$path = "D:\A\d\"
$Dest = "D:\A\d\\$pattern"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Filter *$pattern* | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Move-Item -Destination $Dest
```

I need help to use a loop or any other techinique that will allow me to do this more easily

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the target dir. already exists:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path D:\A\[a-d] |
  Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Filter *$pattern* | 
  Move-Item -Destination { 
    Join-Path ($_.DirectoryName -split '\\')[0..2] $pattern
  } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

If you want to create the target dir. on demand, use
`New-Item -Type Directory -Force (Join-Path ($_.DirectoryName -split '\\')[0..2] $pattern)` - [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item)'s `-Force` switch, when combined with `-Type Directory`, ensures that a preexisting directory, if any, is returned; otherwise, the directory is created; in either case, a [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) instance representing the directory is returned, which stringifies to its `.FullName` property, i.e. to its full, file-system-native path.

Note:

- The *nested* [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) calls are meant to promote conceptual clarity:

  - The outer call uses a PowerShell [wildcard expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) in combination with the `-Directory` switch to match the top-level directories of interest - note the use of character range `[a-d]` to match directories names `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d`.
  - The inner call acts on each resulting directory and recursively searches only for *files* matching the pattern, via the `-File` switch.
  - This approach avoids the need for your `Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false}` call, which - incidentally - can be more PowerShell-idiomatically expressed as `Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer }` and - in [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) - using [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax), `Where-Object -not PSIsContainer`.
  - Note: It is tempting to try a *single* `Get-ChildItem` call such as 
    `Get-ChildItem -Path D:\A\[a-d] -File -Recurse -Filter *$pattern*`, but that doesn't actually work, because the `-File` switch is then applied to *whatever the `D:\A\[a-d]` wildcard expression resolves to*, and since the results are *directories*, `-File` effectively *excludes* them from further processing, resulting in an effective no-op.

    - That is, `-File` in combination with `-Recurse` only works meaningfully for *literal* input paths, to whose *child* (descendant) items the `-File` switch is then applied.
- The [`Move-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item) call uses a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) to dynamically determine the destination directory:

  - `$_.DirectoryName` contains each input file's full directory path, and `(... -split '\\')[0..2]` extracts the ancestral path that is composed of 3 components, such as `D:\A\c`.